# TortoiseSVN: Is there any need for _svn instead of .svn anymore?

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn

A few years ago there was a bug involving ASP.NET and Tortoise/AnkhSvn (can't remember the details), and the solution was to set Tortoise to use "_svn" instead of ".svn" folders for its hidden local files. There's an option for it on the Tortoise settings dialog.

So I still need to do that, or is it not an issue anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is controlled by an `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK` environnment variable, from which I think it is safe to say that the only reason it existed was to solve the problem with ASP.NET. Now that both VS and ASP.NET itself handle `.svn` correctly, I don't think there's a compelling reason to use `_svn` directories.

Comment: Thanks. When did this get fixed, was it back when .NET 2 came out?

Comment: Actually, it was fixed in VS2003 already. Only VS.NET hat this bug.

Comment: Wow, that makes me feel old : )

Comment: @Stefan Somewhat hard to argue with someone who's dev lead on TSVN, but I vividly remember writing a tool to rename `.svn` to `_svn` back in 2005 (http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/src/1294151.aspx , but it's in Russian).