# With TortoiseSVN, can a team use both .svn and _svn for local files?

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn

My team of several developers use TortoiseSVN.  I noticed that after an update at some point in the past, I'm no longer using **_svn** (underscore) as had been our standard for SVN's local hidden files, but rather **.svn** (dot).  Can this cause any issue with our repository or the normal functions of SVN?

**UPDATE**

We are a .net shop, so I imagine that _svn files were originally specified here because of an [old problem that doesn't seem to exist anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513331/tortoisesvn-is-there-any-need-for-svn-instead-of-svn-anymore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not based on the repository it's based on the configuration of TortoiseSVN. I don't know why you use "_svn" which is intended for using in relationship with .net as far as i know. Why not using ".svn" the default in SVN.

Comment: I can't quite tell what your answer is, unfortunately. Will mixing the usage of _ and . across team members result in any harm to our repositories or SVN functionality?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, cause it's only a configuration of the client. The repository doesn't know anything about that except if you accidentally checkin ".svn" or "_svn" ... but that's a different story.